# UIStackView in collectionview layout content jumping

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Using a `UIStackView` in a view in a `UICollectionView` all of the cells are the same size until I scroll away from a cell and then back to it. 
It looks awful like the following image where the top picture is larger than the frame of the screen!

[image]

Here is a view of my constraints:

[image]

CollectionView setup as:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SimpleStackCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil);
collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.delegate = self
```

And I set up the `UICollectionView` as:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 500)
    }
```

Comment: why are you setting `layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)` and then use `sizeForItemAt`????

Comment: Doesn't change when it is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set an estimated size in your layout. According to the doc:

> ```
> open var estimatedItemSize: CGSize // defaults to CGSizeZero - setting a non-zero size enables cells that self-size via -preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:
> ```

So I assume you have a bigger image than your UICollectionViewCell and when you scroll you can see a weird behavior. To avoid it, simply remove the estimated size paramter. You don't need to implement `sizeForItemAt` neither. So your code will look like

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SimpleStackCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil);
collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.delegate = self
```

And last thing, I am not sure you need to set constraints on your placeholder `UIImageView` if your stack view is already set to `alignment = .fill`

Plus, you can replace your width constraint on your `UIStackView` by a trailing constraint.

And maybe you have to set a vertical compression resistance priority on your `UILabel` different to the one of the `UIImageView`.